Rudin's proof of Open Mapping Theorem (5.9 RCA, p. 100)


This is a very minor question about Rudin's proof of the Open Mapping Theorem. I have included his proof if you don't happen to have the book handy.
Just before display (4), Rudin fixes $y \in \delta V$ and $\epsilon > 0$. As far as I can tell, $\epsilon$ does not depend on the choice of $y$. He then shows that $y$ has a preimage $x$ in $(1+\epsilon)U$, from which we conclude that $\Lambda(U)$ contains $(1+\epsilon)^{-1}\delta V$.
My question is this: Aren't we done at this point? Our goal was to show that the image of the unit ball in $X$ contains a ball around $0$ in $Y$, and we've done that: the image contains the ball centered at $0$ with radius $\delta/(1+\epsilon)$.
Are the last sentences purely cosmetic? Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, in fact $\Lambda(U) \supset \delta V$ for the original $\delta$. But strictly speaking, this isn't necessary, is it? The ball of radius $\delta/(1+\epsilon)$ is just as good as the ball of radius $\delta$, I would think... Or is there some dependence on $\epsilon$ that we need to remove from the final conclusion?
Thanks in advance!

You are right. For any $\varepsilon$ the image $\Lambda(U)$ contains a ball $B_\varepsilon$ around $0$. Notice however that $\delta>0$ depends only on the linear operator, so by taking the union, one gets rid of the additional dependence of $\varepsilon$.

Thank you very much!
